# PHP server-side YouTube V3 OAuth API video upload for different users

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth

Currently I am using a modified script to upload videos. I have taken the following example as a basis:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php
This script uses browser based oauth flow.
Could you please tell me if it is possible to allow other users to upload videos to my channel without making them the channel managers? So that they could use my auth token.
If yes - how can it be inplemented?

Comment: Probably if you authenticate it once and safe the refresh token then the script will have access to upload to your account.   You will have to authenticate it using Oauth2.  As far as I know you cant use a service account with Youtube-api so that option is out.

Comment: Hey, DalmTo, I've done all according to this tutorial:
https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide
But it does not as it should:
An client error occurred: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client" }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely possible. You need to design an application that is capable of the following:

1. Authenticate the channel the videos shall be uploaded to via OAuth. As DalmTo said, you need to save the tokens. Whoever has the tokens has access to the channel.
2. Since your application has access to the channel by now, it (and therefore you) can decide what to upload. That means that you are responsible for granting or denying a specific user the right to upload something.
3. In order to do so, you could again use OAuth or any other method you like (e.g. you can use your backend accounts).

In other words, a user has to identify towards your application. Your application can then decide to take the user's content and upload it to the channel.